# Arrays not merging together

Tags: php, arrays

So I have the following two arrays which I try to merge together, the first one as $weekDays:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [start] => 11:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
    )

)
```

And the second array as $all_slots:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
)
```

Using this foreach, I try to loop each $weekDays item and merge it with an $all_slots item which has te same index number:

```
foreach($weekDays as $index => $day){
        $slot = ['slot' => $all_slots[$index]];
        array_merge_recursive($slot, $day);
    }
```

But when I echo the updated $weekDays array it hasn't been merged at all, no errors either. It really does nothing for some reason, what am I missing here? I try to have the following result for the $weekDays array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [start] => 11:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 17:00:00
        [slot] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: 1) `array_merge_recursive()` returns a resulting array! You just ignore that and the result disappears into the ether

Answer (score 2):

`array_merge_recursive()` returns a resulting array which you are not capturing.

A simpler approach would be

```
foreach($weekDays as $index => &$day){
    $day['slot'] = $all_slots[$index];
}
```

> you will have to make sure that the `$all_slots` array has the same or a greater number of occurances as `weekDays`